# Matrix non-singular proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have one question of how to derive the nonsingularity of one matrix. Here's the matrix I'm interested in:

\begin{align}
A = I + SHFG,
\end{align}
where $A \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times m}$, $I\in \mathcal{R}^{m \times m}$ is an identity matrix, $S \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times n}$, $H \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times r}$, $F \in \mathcal{R}^{r \times r}$, and $G \in \mathcal{R}^{r \times m}$ are appripriate constant matrices.

I have seen the proof process from one journal that the matrix $A$ is a non-singular matrix if the following inequality is satisfied:
\begin{align}
S H F G G^T F^T H^T S^T < I.
\end{align}
Why nonsingularity of matrix $A$ is guaranteed if the above inequality is satisfied?

I have tried to understand the proof process by using my knowledge... however, I don't know how to get the conclusion....

Answer (score 2):

Write $A=I+X$ where $X=SHFG$. The given condition means that $I-X^TX$ is positive definite. Now suppose $Av=0$. Then $(I+X)v=0, Xv=-v, v^TX^TXv=v^Tv$ and hence $v^T(I-X^TX)v=0$. Since $I-X^TX$ is positive definite, $v$ must be zero. Hence $A$ is nonsingular.

Comment: Thank you for your clear intuition and wonderful answer......... You save my life!! Thank you!!

Comment: @Hwang if his answer saved your life, then kindly accept his answer.

Comment: @user550103 How can I accept his answer? I don't know how to do that..... Is there any button in the page?

Comment: @user1551 I have one further question. How can I guarantee I-X^T X is positive definite?

Comment: @Hwang This is a given condition in your question.

Comment: If the matrix X = SHFG, I think that the given condition becomes I-XX^T>0. The value of I-XX^T and I-X^T X are the same? My mathematical ability is poor...I can't understand...

Comment: @Hwang $X^TX$ and $XX^T$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues. So, $I-XX^T>0$ is equivalent to $I-X^TX>0$. Alternatively, perform a singular value decomposition on $X$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for your kind answer and clear verification. Thank you so much.